# Is there any easy way to sparsely store a matrix with a redundant pattern in python?

Tags: python, matrix, python-2.7, numpy, sparse-matrix

The type of matrix I am dealing with was created from a vector as shown below:

Start with a 1-d vector V of length L.

To create a matrix A from V with N rows, make the i'th column of A the first N entries of V, starting from the i'th entry of V, so long as there are enough entries left in V to fill up the column. This means A has L - N + 1 columns.

Here is an example:

```
V = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
N = 3

A =
[0 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
 2 3 4 5]
```

Representing the matrix this way requires more memory than my machine has. Is there any reasonable way of storing this matrix sparsely? I am currently storing N * (L - N + 1) values, when I only need to store L values.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a view of your original vector as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> 
>>> v = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> n = 3
>>> 
>>> a = as_strided(v, shape=(n, len(v)-n+1), strides=v.strides*2)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

This is a view, not a copy of your original data, e.g.

```
>>> v[3] = 0
>>> v
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5])
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 4],
       [2, 0, 4, 5]])
```

But you have to be careful no to do any operation on `a` that triggers a copy, since that would send your memory use through the ceiling.

Comment: What if I need to concatenate several of these types of matrices together? Would vstack or hstack work, and if not, how do you create a view of the concatenation of two arrays without concatenating them?

Comment: @user1123936 All you can do with a view is play around with the shape and the strides. While this is a very powerful tool, it only works on acontiguous block of memory. If you try to stack views, you'll trigger a copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using `numpy`, use its strided or sparse arrays, as Jaime explained.

If you're *not* already using `numpy`, you may to strongly consider using it.

If you need to stick with pure Python, there are three obvious ways to do this, depending on your use case.

For strided or sparse-but-clustered arrays, you could do effectively the same thing as `numpy`.

Or you could use a simple run-length-encoding scheme, plus maybe a higher-level list of runs for, or list of pointers to every Nth element, or even a whole stack of such lists (one for every 100 elements, one for every 10000, etc.).

But for mostly-uniformly-dense arrays, the easiest thing is to simply store a `dict` or `defaultdict` mapping indices to values. Random-access lookups or updates are still O(1)—albeit with a higher constant factor—and the storage you waste storing (in effect) a hash, key, and value instead of just a value for each non-default element is more than made up for by not storing values for the default elements, as long as you're less than 0.33 density.